# How to deploy Custom Azure Api App using PowerShell?

Tags: azure-api-apps

We have developed a custom API App connector and have created Logic App using this. We are able to deploy the Custom Api App using Visual Studio but unable to find a way to deploy it using PowerShell.

We have created a deployable zip package for the Api App (similar to Web Apps) but not sure how to publish/deploy it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Api Apps also need to be deployed with an App Service Plan, Gateway Host, Gateway, and an API App Host.

See [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DFsharp/ARMTemplates/master/arm_apiapp_logicapp_template.json) example template.

For more information read here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-arm-with-api-app-provision/

Comment: Unfortunately, the pastebin link is no longer available. That makes the quality of the answer much less valuable.